# Validate input field and restore last valid value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I am trying to set validation on an input field using AngularJS directive, so that when the user types invalid value, the underlying model value changes to the last valid one. This is the contents of the directive:

```
      // returns true/false
      function validateValue(value) {

      }

      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(validateValue);
      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(validateValue);

      scope.$watch(attrs.checkValidName, function() {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
      });
```

So from my understanding, this code will basically run `validateValue` callback on every change of the input value and mark the input field with valid/invalid depending of the return value. This works great for basic validation, but the side effect of this in case the value is invalid, model value won't contain anything.  I'm not sure how to change the code, so that when the value is invalid, the modal value actually contains the last valid value ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can overwrite `$$writeModelToScope` in the [NgModelController](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L714). Only update the scope value if the controller is valid.

```
  ngModelCtrl.$$$writeModelToScope = ngModelCtrl.$$writeModelToScope;
  ngModelCtrl.$$writeModelToScope = function() {
    if (ngModelCtrl.$valid) {
      ngModelCtrl.$$$writeModelToScope();
    }
  };
```

Comment: With this code, user is not able to type invalid value in the input box at all...

Comment: I don't think you can hold old value in same model variable. Model is two-way bound to the view by Angular. How would the framework know what to display? The request is ridiculous by definition

Comment: I think too this is a deep cut into the angular functionality and it's better to keep a shadow value in the scope, which only updates if the value is not undefined.